# How to get compiled down version of dart code

Tags: dart

Is there a way to get compiled down version of a dart code for a particular target? Say the following code compiled for Dart VM.

I'm new to Dart and quite often come across high level abstract code and wonder how it is translated in VM.

`names.forEach(print);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dart is not compiled to something like Java-bytecode or DotNet IL.

Dart is compiled to machine code by the VM either ahead of time (AoT) or just in time (JiT)

https://mrale.ph/dartvm/

> The name "Dart VM" is historical. Dart VM is a virtual machine in a
>   sense that it provides an execution environment for a high-level
>   programming language, however it does not imply that Dart is always
>   interpreted or JIT-compiled, when executing on Dart VM. For example,
>   Dart code can be compiled into machine code using Dart VM AOT pipeline
>   and then executed within a stripped version of the Dart VM, called
>   precompiled runtime, which does not contain any compiler components
>   and is incapable of loading Dart source code dynamically.

Dart 2 uses Kernel AST though generated by the common front-end (CFE)

There is some abstraction happening from the Dart language though

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/kernel/README.md

> Dart Kernel is a small high-level language derived from Dart. It is
>   designed for use as an intermediate format for whole-program analysis
>   and transformations, and to be consumed by codegen and execution
>   backends.
>
> The kernel language has an in-memory representation in Dart and can be
>   serialized as binary or text.

Both the kernel language and its implementations are unstable and are under development.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/kernel/binary.md